# Cannot load picture from internal URI in cordova ios

Tags: ios, image, cordova

I am fetching in objective C the URI of a picture thanks to :

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil
                                   completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                                       NSString *uri =contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL.absoluteString;    
                                   }];
```

It works fine, but after that **I am not able to load a picture** from this URI with `<img src="myURI"/>` in a html page of my **Cordova** app.

The uri looks like

> file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0045.JPG

And trying to load it from a browser navigation bar (safari, chrome) returns a 404 not found.

Also, trying to get the correct URI with

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(newURI,success,error)
```

returned a 404 not found error.

I carefully read the documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) but could not figure out what was wrong :/

Comment: Did you use `NSSLog()` to get uri value?

Comment: Indeed, that's how I found out the URI was file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0045.JPG  :)